# how to limit the number of values to be pushed to an array-JqueryJs

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an json object as follows. I have an array named category that I'm trying to push some values into it.
Here is the Js:

```
var data={
    products : [
        { type: 'fos', name: 'retek' },
        { type: 'testta', name: 'item' },
        { type: 'nyedva', name: 'blabla' }
    ]
};
var categories = [];
```

Now i want to push all the values into the categories array except one:
here is what i tried:

```
$.each(data.products, function(index, mon) {
    if (mon.type == 'testta') {
        //dont push the array
    } else {
        //push it to array
    }
});
```

but this work..any ideas how to achieve this??
Thanks!

Comment: ... I don't get it. "but this work.." Yes, that will work. `categories.push(mon)` is the only thing missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$.each(data.products, function(index, mon) {   
    if (mon.type !== 'testta') {
        categories.push(mon)
    }
});
console.log(categories);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
$.each(data.products, function(index, mon){
    if(mon.type !== 'testta'){
        categories.push(mon)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why that wouldn't work, but typically this is the kind of job you can use [`jQuery.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) for:

```
var categories = $.grep(data.products, function(mon) {
    return mon.type != 'testta';
});
```